# Solubility of white phosphorus

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, allotropes

Why is white phosphorus soluble in $\ce{CS2}$ but red phosphorus not? Is it something in relation with the structures of both? Please explain.

Comment: You can (and should!) use the `\ce{...}` environment to format chemical equations and formulae; see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3046/) for a basic intro and [here](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) for a complete documentation. P/S names of chemicals are not capitalised.

Comment: What do you know about white phosphorus, to begin with?

Comment: @IvanNeretin That white phosphorus is tetrahedral closed ${P_4}$ molecule and red phosphorus is kind of open structure formed from ${P_4}$ molecule.

Comment: That's it, then. To dissolve red phosphorus, you'd have to break covalent bonds, which is hard. Dissolving white phosphorus is much easier.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Then what kind of bonds are in $P_4$ molecule in white phosphorus among $P-P$ atoms aren't the covalent ?Do we need to break $P-P$ bonds Or  the interactions between two $P_4$ molecules while considering solubility?

Comment: **Within** $\rm P_4$ molecule, there are of course covalent bonds. No, we don't have to break those.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So are the interactions between $P_4$ molecules Van der Waals attaractions ?

Comment: That's right, and those are weak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White phosphorus has P4 molecules packed into a crystal,these dissolve readily in Carbon Disulfide.

[image]

Whereas Red phosphorus is polymeric in nature. It is a derivative of white phosphorus where one P-P bond is broken and an addtional bond is formed with neighboring tetrahedron molecule resulting in a chain like structure .

[image]

Like all long chain polymers this will lower its ability to dissolve and its solubility in solvents